# How can I access environments in Exec gradle

Tags: gradle

I want to run a command in gradle with specific envroment variables.

But I can't access them

```
tasks {
    register<Exec>("run"){
        environment(mapOf(
                "NAME" to "mohammad",
            ))
        executable = "echo"
        argumentProviders.add { listOf(
            "$NAME"
        )}
        //  commandLine ("bash", "-c",
        //      "echo $NAME"
        //  )
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve? The `environment` block will set environment variables for the executed process, but they won't be available in Gradle itself.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings thanks, you are right. I thought that we can access that variable in gradle.